# How to store data from a picker view in a variable when a button is pressed?

Tags: swift, ios8, uipickerview

I have a picker view with one component that I populated with an array of data. When the user presses a button, I want the selected data in that row to be stored in a variable so that I can send it to another view controller using a segue, where it will be displayed in a label. The only part I'm having trouble with is actually getting that data to be stored in order to be used somewhere else. I know that using a datePicker, I can do something like  this to do what I want:

`@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
var chosenDate: NSDate = self.datePicker.date
}`

This will store the date selected by the user in the var chosenDate, which is what I want for my pickerView when a button is pressed. I'm aware also that I can get that data in a pickerView using

`func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)`

The only problem with this is that it selects the data every single time a user changes the value, and it doesn't allow me to store the data in a variable outside the function for me to use it in my @IBAction func buttonPressed method. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after trying different things I finally came up with a solution to my problem. It might not be what the more experienced developers do but it worked for me just like I wanted. Here is what I did:

```
@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    var chosen = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    var chosenString = arrayPopulatingThePickerView[chosen]

}
```

I only have one component in the pickerView i need therefore when the button is pressed I store the row number of the component 0 in a variable, then I store the string in another variable by making it equal to the array I used to populate my picker view. I retrieve the row by passing it the chosen variable.

Comment: That works well, except you should use `let` instead of `var` if you don't need the data to be mutable.

Comment: You're right, I'll change that right away. Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 1):

> You can create a function to store this date using NSUserDefaults.
>   This way you can access it everywhere and anytime (even after closing
>   the app).

```
func saveChosenDate(date:NSDate){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(date, forKey: "chosenDate")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

> to load it:

```
func loadChosenDate()-> NSDate{
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("chosenDate") as NSDate
}
```

> to delete/reset the value of it:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("chosenDate")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

> save it

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    saveChosenDate(datePicker.date)
}
```

> load it

```
let myDate = loadChosenDate()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's great when working with a datePicker, but I'm trying to work with a picker view with custom data, such as apples, oranges, grapes or 1,2,3,4,5. Please let me know if you have an idea of how I can solve this. Cheers!

Comment: Your code shows you trying to create a NSDate object

Comment: I think you should post another question

Comment: I'm actually trying to do with a picker view the same thing I did with the date picker above, but you're right my question probably wasn't that clear.